# SSIS package version GUID does not stay stable between runs

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, visual-studio

We have a large quantity of SSIS packages created in visual studio 2008. Currently running on hundreds of servers.
We are logging the details of each package before it runs.

One of the things we are logging is the PackageVersionGUID to verify if the correct/latest stable version was run each day.
However when we look at our logging, each run shows a different PackageVersionGUID.

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.versionguid.aspx) :

> the version GUID generated when the package is first created.

Why then do we see different GUID's each time, and in fact don't have a single recurrence of the GUID?

The most blatant example of this is when we run our package in a loop to connect to several servers in succession.
Each time the loop starts, it logs its PackageVersionGUID, and each time the ID is different.

To be clear, we have since replaced the logging with *VersionMajor.VersionMinor.VersionBuild* which serves our purposes. So I am not asking for a different way to log our package versions.
But I would like to know why the GUID was not a correct approach, and why it changes so frequently (or perhaps a confirmation that the MSDN documentation is simply wrong).